# Can i use the data in the version tag from the pom file, in a maven project, and use it in the build configuration of idea intellij directly?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have a maven project and the snapshot number in the version tags change frequently. I manually make the change in the path to jar field of build>edit configurations each time. Is there anyway i can directly access this from the pom file?

Comment: read from properties file. if version changes in regular manner then write and read from the file

Comment: What do you mean by snapshot number ?